# What Configuration i need for real time streaming with audio at 720p?

Tags: video-streaming, streaming, iot, hardware-interface, hardware

I am planning for IoT project that streams 720p RTSP or RTMP with audio at 60FPS with WIFI.
I need to know what processor speed and what ram i will need on IoT board to stream it online with cloud and show on end mobile device.
Also any other hardware i need then please let me know.

Thanks